# Error while compiling: The error - [Terminated due to signal: ABORT TRAP (6)]

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, undefined-behavior

Error while compiling: The error - [Terminated due to signal: ABORT TRAP (6)]

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int j, r = 2, p = 1;
    int v[8];
    for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    {
        v[j - p] = 3 * j - r;
        p = -p;
        r = r - p;
    }
    for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        cout << v[j] << " ";
}
```

Comment: What do you think will happen when j = 0?

Comment: What compiler are you using and how are you compiling this code? It compiles here: https://ideone.com/r4CyuA Perhaps you are compiling successfully and have a runtime error?

Comment: xluci fr: A compiler should _never_ crash, no matter what you throw at it - so if this is in fact happening while you are compiling we need to know what @RetiredNinja asked about to have a fair chance of providing an answer.

Comment: @TedLyngmo FWIW, that's a Xcode kind of runtime error, probably clang.

Comment: @anastaciu It's most likely a runtime error.in OP:s program, but nothing rules out a runtime error in the IDE or the compiler. I'm guessing it's a debugger SIGTRAP fireing.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, yes , could be.

Comment: @RetiredNinja it's CodeRunner, here is a [link](https://coderunnerapp.com)

Comment: @xluci.fr your comment doesn't clarify things all that much, does it still happen if you correct your code, say using `for (j = 1; j < 8; j++)`? instead of `j = 0`?

Comment: Try compiling with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`

Comment: And add `-fsanitize=address` to `g++` for good measure.

Comment: Hey @anastaciu thanks for your help! Can you help me out with other codes that have some similar issues?

Comment: @xluci.fr of course, and don't forget, to vote in the bellow answers and/or [accept one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/684852) if you feel it helped you solve your problem.

Comment: Ok @anastaciu, so this one has the same issue: `#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main() {
 int i, j; int t[4][4];
 for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
 for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
  if (i != j) t[5 - i][5 - j] = 3 * i - j;
 else t[i][j] = i % j;
 for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
  for (j = 1; j <= 4; j++) cout << t[i][j] << " ";
  cout << endl;
 }
}`

Comment: And also @anastaciu this one: `#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main() {
 int i, j; int t[4][4];
 for (i = 3; i <= 6; i++)
 for (j = 2; j <= 5; j++)
  if (i > j) t[i - 2][j - 1] = i + j;
 else t[i - 2][j - 1] = i / j;
 for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
  for (j = 1; j <= 4; j++) cout << t[i][j] << " ";
  cout << endl;
 }
}`

Comment: @anastaciu can you also comment what the problem is with these two codes

Comment: In the first one your array is `t[4][4]` but you are accessing index `[4][4]` which is effectivly line 5 column 5, since indexes start at 0, you need to either make your array bigger `t[5][5]` or fix the access in the for loops. replacing `<=` with `<`, note that the nested `for` also uses `i` you may have meant to use `j` instead.

Comment: The second code is the same, accessing the array out of bounds, you can fix it by replacing **all** the `<=` in the `for` loops, with `<` only.

Answer (score 0):

Your program invokes undefined behavior, when `j` is 0, you will be writing in `v[-1]`, arrays don't have negative indexes.

That said, there is nothing in your code that stops it from compiling.

Answer (score 0):

At least this statement

```
v[j - p] = 3 * j - r;
```

invokes undefined behavior because there is an attempt to access memory beyond the array when for example `j` is equal to `0` and `p` is equal to `1` or when `j` is equal to `7` and `p` is equal to `-1`. In these cases you will get indices `-1` and `8` that are not valid for the array `v`.

So the program is aborted after it was ran.